# Add New Token in TokenEdit (DevExpress)

Tags: c#, winforms, token, devexpress

I am using the TokenEdit control from devexpress.

I need to convert the plain text to a token in the code.

The documentation says that to validate plain text and convert it to token and you are using a bound datasource then you should handle the ProcessNewValue event. The documentation also provides an example

```csharp
void TokenEdit1_ProcessNewValue(object sender, TokenEditProcessNewValueEventArgs e) {
    if (MailRegex.IsMatch(e.Text)) {
        //use data source API to post changes
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

and gives the following comment:

> Handle it to check the user input, and if you accept it as a valid token, add a corresponding new record to the data source.

Now my code, how I handle the event:

```csharp
private async void TagEditor_ProcessNewValue(object sender, TokenEditProcessNewValueEventArgs e)
{
  e.Value = await RepositoryHelper.TagRepository.SaveValueAndGetIdBack<int>(e.Text);
  var tag = (Tag)TagSource.AddNew();

  tag.Id = (int)e.Value;
  tag.Description = e.Text;
  TagSource.EndEdit();

  e.Handled = true;
}
```

TagSource is simple BindingSource with assigned List.

I intent to accept any plain text as a valid token, so I don`t have a condition, but the plain text is not converted into the token at all.

Can anyone give me a hint? what am I doing wrong?